# How to split long table into two adjacent colums?

Tags: tables, longtable, columns

I'm having issues with transforming long table into two adjacent colums.
The code looks like this:

```
    {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.0}
    \noindent\begin{longtable*}{@{}l @{\quad=\quad} l@{}}
    $1$             & a\\
    $2$           & b\\
    $3$           & c\\
    $4$             & d\\
    $5$           & e\\
    $6$           & f\\
    $7$             & g\\
    $8$           & h\\
    $9$           & i\\
    $10$             & j\\
    \end{longtable*}}
```

The desirable output is two-adjacent tables with 5 rows in each one.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! is your table really long table? From your code snippet this is not so obvious). Please extend it to complete small document with your table, which begins with `\document{class` and end with `\end{document}˙˙. BTW, `longtable*` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

- It is impossible to have two long tables in parallel
- Regarding your code fragment, you should be aware that

  - `longtable* doesn't exist. Exist only` table*`or`figure` floats environments in which you can enclose (short) tables or images. Thpse floats spam two columns in document and apear at top of the next page from insertion point.
  - `longtable` is always horizontally centered in text area. For flus left it you need to set (in preamble)

```
\setlength\LTleft
\setlength\LTright\fill
```

or simpler

```
\begin{longtable}[l]{...}
```

- The command `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.0}` hasn't any sence. Default array stretch is `1`.
- `longtable` has defined `firsthead` `head`, `foot` and `lastfoot` ... do you need them?

Your "longtable" can be extend to quasi in parallel tables on the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, % deleta this option in real document
            vmargin=63mm, hmargin=33mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{longtable}{@{} l l @{\qquad} l l @{}}
    $1$         & a     &   $2$         & b\\
    $3$         & c     &   $4$         & d\\
    $5$         & e     &   $6$         & f\\
    $7$         & g     &   $8$         & h\\
    $9$         & i     &   $10$        & j\\
    \end{longtable}

    
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ ll }
\hline
    $1$           & a\\
    $2$           & b\\
    $3$           & c\\
    $4$           & d\\
    $5$           & e\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\quad % if needed space between table
\begin{tabular}{ ll }
\hline
    $6$           & f\\
    $7$           & g\\
    $8$           & h\\
    $9$           & i\\
    $10$          & j\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(gray lines indicate page layout)

Comment: simpler to use `[l]` to get flush left longtable  (not that that helps get two side by side)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you very much to remained me for this! Happy New Year!